# Check if file is alias Swift

Tags: macos, swift, nsfilemanager

How can I check if a file is an Alias on Mac? Here is my code so far:

```swift
public func getFiles(){
    let folderPath = "/Users/timeBro/Desktop/testfolder"
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let enumerator:NSDirectoryEnumerator = fileManager.enumeratorAtPath(folderPath)!
    
    for url in enumerator.allObjects {
        
        let newurl = NSURL(string: url as! String)
        print("\(url as! String)")
        print(url);
        print(newurl?.isFileReferenceURL())
    }
}
```

How can I check if the file is an alias?

Comment: you are right. it is working but i will change that. the problem is still the alias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: I initially mistakenly assumed that the only option is to use a *CoreFoundation* (C API) method, but that's not actually true ([thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33349364/45375)): the *Foundation* (ObjC API) class `NSURL` does provide a way to detect Finder aliases:

```
// OSX 10.9+
// Indicates if the specified filesystem path is a Finder alias.
// Returns an optional Boolean: if the lookup failed, such when the path doesn't exist,
// nil is returned.
// Example: isFinderAlias("/path/to/an/alias")
func isFinderAlias(path:String) -> Bool? {
    let aliasUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    var isAlias:AnyObject? = nil
    do {
        try aliasUrl.getResourceValue(&isAlias, forKey: NSURLIsAliasFileKey)
    } catch _ {}
    return isAlias as! Bool?
}
```

---

**[Not recommended, except as an exercise in using `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>`]**
Here's how to do it with the C-based CoreFoundation API:

- `IsAliasFile()` was deprecated in OS X 10.4,
- succeeded by `FSIsAliasFile()`, which was deprecated in 10.8.
- The current method is to use `CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey()`, which isn't fun to deal with in Swift, due to having to use manual memory management with `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>`.

I hope I got the memory management right:

```
import Foundation

// Indicates if the specified filesystem path is a Finder alias.
// Returns an optional Boolean: if the lookup failed, such when the path
// doesn't exist, nil is returned.
// Example: isFinderAlias("/path/to/an/alias")
func isFinderAlias(path:String) -> Bool? {

    var isAlias:Bool? = nil // Initialize result var.

    // Create a CFURL instance for the given filesystem path.
    // This should never fail, because the existence isn't verified at this point.
    // Note: No need to call CFRelease(fUrl) later, because Swift auto-memory-manages CoreFoundation objects.
    let fUrl = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(nil, path, CFURLPathStyle.CFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false)

    // Allocate void pointer - no need for initialization,
    // it will be assigned to by CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey() below.
    let ptrPropVal = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>.alloc(1)

    // Call the CoreFoundation function that copies the desired information as
    // a CFBoolean to newly allocated memory that prt will point to on return.
    if CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey(fUrl, kCFURLIsAliasFileKey, ptrPropVal, nil) {

        // Extract the Bool value from the memory allocated.
        isAlias = UnsafePointer<CFBoolean>(ptrPropVal).memory as Bool

        // Since the CF*() call contains the word "Copy", WE are responsible
        // for destroying (freeing) the memory.
        ptrPropVal.destroy()
    }

    // Deallocate the pointer
    ptrPropVal.dealloc(1)

    return isAlias
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Before I post another question. How would I get the filepath of the document the alias is pointing to?

Comment: @Silve2611: That's even more involved, so I suggest you ask a new question; the documentation says "First use CFURLCreateBookmarkDataFromFile, then use CFURLCreateByResolvingBookmarkData." Feel free to notify me here once you've asked the new question, if you still need help.

Comment: Ok I will. I also did a great part of it already but I only get the Fileid not the path.

Comment: I added the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348653/getting-alias-path-of-file-in-swift

Comment: @Silve2611: While my original answer worked, I've led you down the wrong path: there _is_ a more convenient, Foundation-based way of doing this, using `NSURL` - please see my update.

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy solution which completely gets by without any pointer handling:

```
extension URL {
    func isAlias() -> Bool? {
        let values = try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.isSymbolicLinkKey, .isAliasFileKey])
        let alias = values?.isAliasFile
        let symbolic = values?.isSymbolicLink

        guard alias != nil, symbolic != nil else { return nil }
        if alias! && !symbolic! {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Explanation: `resourceValues(forKeys:)` returns `.isAliasFile` **and** `.isSymbolicLink` for symbolic links so you have to make sure the former is returned and the latter isn’t when checking for aliases.
If the path doesn’t exist the function returns nil.